# Unity Facebook SDK 5.1 email permission not granted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, unity-game-engine

I just followed the tutorial of unity sdk about friend smash, I used unity 4.3 and the sdk is 5.1.

I followed the tutorial until the personalize section here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial#personalize

I stopped here because I want to get not only the user name but the email too, the thing is I can't do it.

I even checked the permisions granted, but only  public_profile and user_friends are grantend. I'm using the FB.Login function like this:

```
FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
```

But even this way I don't have access to the email field.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you test it on the android platform. I found the email permission was not granted when testing the app in a PC build, but when deployed onto an Android device the permission was correctly granted for email.

Note: Had the same problem with Unity SDK 6.0.